# Unable to run the react-native app on emulator and on real devise at a time

Tags: react-native

When i try to run the react-native app on emulator and on real devise, getting following error,

```
 error: more than one device/emulator
```

Is there any way to prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your project on one device only, so you have to choose between the emulator or your phone.

> If multiple devices are running, you must specify the target device when you issue the adb command.

Although, you can switch between them with [a simple command](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#directingcommands).

Comment: for native android app it not possible to run in two devices. But it's possible for react-native app.In my case I am facing this issue only in few cases and unable to findout the reason

Comment: May you specify the cases then? It's hard to tell without any hints